# Solve trig equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry, homework

I have a simple trig equation:

```
Clear[f, x]
f[x_] = Cos[2*x] - 3 Sin[x] + 2
Solve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

I received a very long a complicated reply that I do not understand.

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[\[Pi] - 
     ArcTan[(-3 + Sqrt[33])/(2 Sqrt[2 (-1 + 3/4 (-3 + Sqrt[33]))])] + 
     2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[(-3 + Sqrt[33])/(2 Sqrt[2 (-1 + 3/4 (-3 + Sqrt[33]))])] + 
     2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[-I Sqrt[1/2 (1 - 3/4 (-3 - Sqrt[33]))], 
      1/4 (-3 - Sqrt[33])] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTan[I Sqrt[1/2 (1 - 3/4 (-3 - Sqrt[33]))], 
      1/4 (-3 - Sqrt[33])] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

What is wrong with my formulation of the question?

Comment: `Solve[]`is used to solve polynomial equations. Try `FindRoot`!

Comment: use `Solve[f[x] == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0` or `Assuming[{Element[C[1], Integers]}, Simplify@Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]`  to get one of infinitely many (periodic) solutions.

Comment: `Reduce[f[x] == 0, x] // ToRadicals`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem using Solve or NSolve:

```
 Solve[{f[x] == 0, 0 < x < 2 Pi}, x] // N
 (*{{x -> 0.756171}, {x -> 2.38542}} *)
```

or using FindRoot with initial condition

```
 FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0}]
 (* {x -> 0.756171}*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do this without the angle constraints.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[f, x];
f[x_] = Cos[2*x] - 3 Sin[x] + 2;

FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]

Solve[{Cos[2*x] - 3 Sin[x] + 2 == 0, 0 < x < 2 Pi}, x] // ToRadicals // Simplify
N[%]

Solve[(Solve[Cos[2*x] - 3 Sin[x] + 2 == 0, x] /. {Rule -> Equal, List -> Or}) &&
 0 < x < 2 Pi, x] // RootReduce // ToRadicals // Normal
N[%]
```

[image]